# How to review a First Post question that clearly belongs on another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, migration

I was doing some First Posts reviews and I came across a question about **Unix**.

The question did *look ok*, but it does not belong on Stack Overflow.

What should I do? Mark *Looks OK* and then move it to another site?

Comment: Was this in First Posts or Triage?  (And do we need both, anyway?)

Comment: Changed the tittle, thanks @JeffreyBosboom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, first do a sanity-check: plenty of Unix questions are on-topic for SO. Please don't be one of those people who knee-jerks on everything that mentions the topic of another site; if it's about programming or programming tools then leave it be...

Ok, so far so good? Completely off-topic? Choose "unsalvageable" then close it as off-topic. Maybe leave a comment noting the existence of a Unix & Linux site.

Comment: This was in the First Posts queue, not Triage, so 'unsalvageable' is not an option (though flagging/voting to close is of course still possible).  (Long-term, will First Post questions just go into Triage?)

Comment: There's no "looks ok" in FP either... This was kind of a confusing question. And yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Don't choose "looks ok" unless it really looks good exactly as it is. I would click "unsalvageable" then move it in the flag dialog that shows up.