# Reviewing the same question in First Posts and Triage

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I just reviewed a question in First Posts and suggested an edit. While my edit was still pending, I saw the same question again in Triage. I suppose this isn’t much of a problem, but it seems strange. Since I am not likely to contradict my previous review, asking me to review the same question again doesn’t accomplish much. Should the review system prevent users from reviewing the same question more than once?

Here are the reviews:

- [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6951321)
- [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6951300)

Comment: According to Shog, First Posts will eventually be replaced by Triage, per [the comments here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280850/how-to-review-a-first-post-question-that-clearly-belongs-on-another-stackexchang/280852#comment132659_280852).